# Android how to reduce drawable layer-list GPU overdraw

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-drawable, gpu-overdraw

I create simple example. Take a look
[image]

It's a simple layout

LinearLayout with children

- Relative - bg = test_drawable_1
- Relative - bg = test_drawable_2
- Relative - bg = test_drawable_3
- Relative - bg = test_drawable_4
- Relative - bg = test_drawable_5

Each test_drawable it's a drawable xml file with layer-list root element and shapes. Each number it's a count of shapes

With more layers of shapes overdraw will grow

**Layout**

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:background="@drawable/test_drawable_1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"></RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:background="@drawable/test_drawable_2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:background="@drawable/test_drawable_3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:background="@drawable/test_drawable_4"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:background="@drawable/test_drawable_5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**test_drawable_1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/gs_GridSize2x" />
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="1dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#95C4CF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Is exists any way to reduce GPU overdraw with drawable layer-list xml?